# How to prevent form inputs clearing in servlets?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am creating a dynamic web project in eclipse using servlets.

Once I submited the form with username and password fields in `index.html` page. When username or password is incorrect, the servlet class should display the `index.html` page again with the data entered in the input fields except password fields, but it is not showing any data in input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the username and password in response and read it in jsp.
You need to make jsp to display values.
You can set Object using
 eg request.setAttribute("cust",customer); 
Read above object in jsp and display values in jsp.